# How to limit users on which Application permissions apply?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am building an application that relies on MS Graph API that will run as background service to create meetings (Events) on behalf of a Room (resource) and which can invite users to the meeting.

Because this is a background service acting on behalf of a room, I cannot ask for user authorization, therefore I can't use the `/authorize` endpoint.

One requirement is that the application must not have access to the users Calendars. I should only have access to the rooms' calendars.

I am able to do what is required, minus restricting the app's access to everyone's calendar. The permission I am using is Application.Calendars.ReadWrite. From what I understand, this gives me access to all Calendars.

The Delagated.Calenders.ReadWrite permission is closer to what I need, but I can't ask for crendentials.

Is there a way to restrict the users I have access to when using Application.Calendars.ReadWrite?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to scope the Application permissions to just the Mailboxes you require using the following https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/scoping-microsoft-graph-application-permissions-to-specific-exchange-online-mailboxes/